# Algebraic geometry and PDEs (reference-request)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, differential-equations

**Context:** Let's say we have an affine algebraic variety corresponding to the zero set of an irreducible polynomial (over $\mathbb{C}$) in $n$ variables, denoted by $p(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. $$p(x_1, \dots, x_n)=0 $$ Now if there are any solution functions $f: \mathbb{C}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{C}$ to the PDE $$p\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_{n-1}}, f\right)=0 $$ (or to any of the PDEs corresponding to permutations of the entries) these functions can be used to parametrize the algebraic variety, and in some cases to glean topological information about it.

The (typical) sinusoidal functions, the hyperbolic sinusoidal functions, and the Weierstrass $\wp$ functions can all be derived in this manner. I don't think it is an overstatement to say that all of these functions are important.

**Question:** Is there any research field or literature using this observation to apply the theory of ODEs or PDEs to that of algebraic geometry, or vice versa?

**Further thoughts:** Since both fields are difficult, I imagine that any field combining the two would be extremely difficult. That being said, this seems like such an obvious to way to think about so many special functions, plus it seems to only involve first order PDEs, that it seems very difficult for me to believe that no one has given this even a cursory investigation before.

As an aside, I imagine that turning the Bessel differential equation into a system of first order ODEs would allow one to derive a correspondence between the Bessel functions and the ideal generated by multiple polynomials (i.e. non-principal but finitely generated), although I haven't figured out how to define a correspondence between systems of first order differential equations and algebraic sets.

Comment: Algebraic Analysis for the complex case. Take a look at the work of Sato, Kashiwara and Schapira on D-modules and hyperfunctions. For the real case, there's the work of Malgrange on Lie pseudogroups using techniques from alg. geom. like infinitesimal neighborhood of the diagonal

Comment: Do people think of special functions as solutions to specific differential equations? Yes, look up [holonomic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_function). Do people think about PDEs of the type you wrote down? Yes, look up the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). Both subjects live quote well outside of algebraic geometry, but can probably take advantage of it when faced with polynomial equations. I'm afraid you'd need to ask a more specific question about that.